# window handling in selenium (python)

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, window-handles

My simple script written in python (selenium) need to click on number of hyperlinks (around 25) in a single web page, each time need to assert something in a new window opened.

I am using the following function to navigate between the windows, which also works well.

```
def go_window(self, window_name = None):
    if window_name is None:
        self.driver.switch_to_window(self.window_handle)
    else:
        self.driver.switch_to_window(window_name)
```

However, it does not close the new window opened each time (also because, links in my page open up the new page each time it is clicked :( ).

I would want to close the new window after asserting.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`WebDriver.close`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html?highlight=close#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.close) method, which closes the current window:

```
self.driver.close()
```